# Cypher query to return one of each sub-nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the graph below ([try it in the neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=pretty_graph)). Starting in the middle, how can I write a cypher-query that limits the results to only include one from each 2-level node, e.g. returning only the red nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm  assuming you want choose by random on the second level. In this case the following Cypher statement does the job:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index("name:start")
MATCH (n)-[:link]->(first)
WITH first
MATCH first-[:link]->(second)
WITH first, collect(second) AS coll
RETURN first, coll[toInt(length(coll)*rand())]
```

We use `collect` to put 2nd degree nodes into a collection for each `first` node. Using the array subscript operator we pick one of the elements by random. `rand()` returns a value between 0 and <1, so we need to multiply with collection length.

Comment: You can also just return coll[0].

Comment: i believe he wanted to pick up the node with highest `Id` (or some int parameter). anyhow, your 2x match query could be simplified just to `MATCH (n)-[:link]->(first), first-[:link]->(second)`

Comment: Yes, actually I did want it sorted, but I figured it out; Had to throw in an additional with statement together with the order by clause. Because there isn't any way to sort a collection, right?

Comment: That seems the way to go.